Execution time is not showing for javascript under Sources tab in Chrome devtools
I have started the recording for my page under chrome dev tools performance tab. After I complete the recording and analyse the performance, I find that one specific javascript is take longer time. when I click on that javascript, it opens in sources tab, but not showing execution time for individual lines inside a javascript function. How to enable it?
Here is my screenshot.
Image without timeline :

Image with timeline:

I have started the recording for my page under chrome dev tools performance tab. After I complete the recording and analyse the performance, I find that one specific javascript is take longer time. when I click on that javascript, it opens in sources tab, but not showing execution time for individual lines inside a javascript function. How to enable it?
